# knockout js .net load page with and without model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I am trying to reuse the same form for adding and editing employee information. I am using knockout js and on my view I make the knockout model:

```
var koModel = new EmployeeModel(div);
```

and if I want to populate the fields from the server I want to do something like this:

```
var koModel = new EmployeeModel(unserializedModelFromController, div);
```

I was wondering what is the best way to distinguish if the request is for a new employee or if it is to edit an existing employee.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you turn your parameters around you can write a single constructor function.

```
var EmployeeModel = function(div, model) {
  if (model) {
    // Existing model has been passed, it's an edit request
  } else {
    // No model has been passed, it's a new request
  }
}
```

This can be called like:

```
new EmployeeModel(div);
```

or

```
new EmployeeModel(div, model);
```

Comment: What if I always pass data from the controller like if its a new employee i pass the name of who is creating it, otherwise I pass in the employee model?

Comment: Sure... you can look at the "model" object and if it's a string do one thing, and otherwise do another.  Use `if (typeof model === 'string')` to determine if you are passing a String.

Comment: Although... if you are always going to return something from the Controller you may want to return an initialized object, with any defaults set, and a null `id` field.  If the `id` is `null` assume it is a new object and if `id` is  set then assume it is an edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a parameter with a default value to the view.
If you are editing an employee, you can send the value of id, you're creating not send.
The function that receives a request to store or edit could have a default value.

```
public void SaveOrEditEmployee(int id=0, ...) //id=0 is a default value
{
    if(id==0)
    {
        //SaveEmployee
    }else
    {
        //EditEmployee
        Employee empl = (x => employee.id == id);
        ...
    }
}
```

Or you can do likewise, receive full model and assess whether the property 'id' already exists in your database